# What is this repeating bubble underneath my coffee cup?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

What is this bubble underneath my coffee cup? The coffee is not at boiling temperature ($\approx$20s after pouring into the cup from the kettle), there is a small amount of water that can be seen just underneath the cup on the right. The bubble has its origin where the water appears to end. Why would the bubble form here and what is the origin of the bubble?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Very likely you have a pocket of air under your coffee cup, trapped by water from all around.

The air temperature will be roughly an average between the temperature of the cup and table underneath it. Initially, the table temperature will grow faster than the cup temperature drops (because coffee is a good thermal reservoir).

Therefore, the air pocket slowly expands, extruding little bubbles through a notch/scratch in the cup bottom.